# access a class/component procedure from a different class / as property

Tags: delphi

I#m in trouble calling an function of an class of a different form, this class is shared between both classes as a property of the second class

```
TMyClass = class
private

public
procedure onconnect (...);

end;


TFormA = class(TForm)

MYCLASS : TMyClass;

procedure StartFormB(...)

end;


TFormA.procedure StartFormB(...)
begin

  bForm.MYCLASS := MyClass;

  bForm.Show;

end; 


TFormB = class(TForm)
private
....
FMYCLASS : TMyClass;
public
......
.....
property MYCLASS : TMyClass  read FMYCLASS write FMYCLASS; 

end;
```

Assume TMyClass is something like a Indy TCP server, how to call the class event procedure onconnect(..)  or onexecute(..) function inside bForm just having the access to shared class instance via the property ?

this is easy

```
 aForm : TMyForm;


 aForm.onconnect(...);
```

this procedure is linked to the class event procedure 
but 
      bForm.FMyClass.onconnect(...)

does not work, I can not build alink to the class event procedure  ...

Comment: `MyClass.XXX` calls a method named `XXX`. That's so obvious it cannot be the answer. So I think you need to improve the question.

Comment: Also, please don't call an object `MyClass`. You must learn the difference between a class and an object. An object is an instance of a class. In your code, `MYCLASS` and `FMYCLASS` are not classes. They are instances, or objects. Name them accordingly.

Comment: The same for `OnConnect()`. The `On` prefix is _reserved_ for event properties, rename it to `Connect()`.

Comment: Of course you cannot access `FMyClass`. It's private. Please don't ever say "does not work". Always provide full details of any error that you see. Pasted verbatim. Don't make us guess. We cannot see your screen. Try writing and debugging code with your eyes closed and see how easy it is.

Comment: I don't see how anyone could answer this question given very simple syntax errors. Must have been typed directly into StackOverflow. For example: `TFormA.procedure StartFormB(...)` ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the question is how to be able to call a method from an object property of a class in another unit, then the answer is:

- Ensure that the object property is declared **public** or **published**,
- Ensure that the method is declared **public**.

Calling the method then is done by:

```
begin
  FormA.MyClass.OnConnect();
```

---

From you edit it is understood that you actually were not trying to call the **property** but the private **field** behind it. That does not work, intentionally. Properties are *designed* to protect the actual value behind them. In your case, the access specifier for reading the property redirects the compiler directly to the private field, but it also could have been a function.

Thus: call the property (`MyClass`), not the field (`FMyClass`).

Comment: i changed the question text above;  bForm.FMyClass.OnConnect(); this does not act as if I#m calling the FormA.MyClass.OnConnect();